# how to create ontology using xml?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, rdf

How to create an ontology for a web  system  using XML ?

I am new to this subject(ontology), i have this project where i need to create a basic ontology using xml tree as backend and frontend using Ajax and PHP/Javascript.

I know Ajax and XML but have no idea about ontologies, so please suggest some good resources and examples. (I have already checked the wikipedia page it was not much of help for practical implementation)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is like asking "how to cook pancakes with a spoon?". You don't cook pancakes with a spoon although you may be using one in the process. Whether you use a spoon or not is irrelevant with respect to how to cook pancakes. Same thing here for XML with respect to how to create an ontology.

Answer (score 0):

you can use
OWL Web Ontology Language
or
[www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMaQgKPrpwo‎](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMaQgKPrpwo%E2%80%8E)
This video might be helpful for you.

Comment: how can i use the results from ontology to answer queries using the frontend